# Rollup, install peer dependencies - what am I supposed to do?

Tags: npm-install, rollupjs, material-components-web

What does the warning message mean? What am I supposed to do? (There is a long list of warnings that looks similar to this.)

> test>npm install @material/mwc-textarea
>
> npm WARN @rollup/plugin-commonjs@21.0.1 requires a peer of
> rollup@^2.38.3 but none is installed. You must install peer
> dependencies yourself

---

EDIT: Some clarifications as suggested by @Konstantin Lyakh. I understand "peer dependencies" as described [here](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/). And the version info as described [here](https://michaelsoolee.com/npm-package-tilde-caret/#:%7E:text=npm%20uses%20the%20package.,each%20section%20with%20different%20meaning.&text=you%20see%20%5E1.0.-,2%20it%20means%20to%20install%20version%201.0.,patch%20version%20such%20as%201.1.).

But I do not understand how this fits together. I have the latest version of rollup installed (v2.67.2). As I understand it this should work with the requirement `rollup@^2.38.3` but the WARNING suggest it does not. (And the `mwc-textarea` does not work as far as I can see.)

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you not understand what peer dependency is? Or do you not understand whether you need rollup or not?

Comment: @KonstantinLyakh I have added clarifications as you suggesed.

Comment: Can you share your code somehow?

Comment: @KonstantinLyakh What code are you thinking of? The error happens in the call to `npm` in the question.

Comment: I created a new empty project and ran "npm install @material/mwc-textarea". No errors. So there must be some additional conditions for the error to appear. Try putting your test project to github repo and share it here.